# Post request failed with error code 400 when submitting Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, http-status-code-400, urlfetch

I am trying to automate data entry in Google forms and following is my code but I am getting

> Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server:...

```
function myFunction() {
  var formUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLScbvM7LZJEL-Cv-Bc1mg1Tid_R2QujW0N4Z4ytfsnztpz9_1A/formResponse";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    var datamap = {
      "entry.1870580307": r[0],
      "emailAddress": r[1],
      "entry.172794055": r[2],
      "entry.2041507911": r[3],
      "entry.981764969": r[4],
      "entry.1599200340": r[5],
      "entry.835533968": r[6],
      "entry.652935633": r[7]
    };
    var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": datamap
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl, options);
  });
}
```

[Link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10XyUEowzDZMZWWCfsEdAkOuMhLVzjH2FZMKv2IIfkW8/edit#gid=0) ,
[Google Form link](https://forms.gle/SCoP8gG9C1vCJeFT9)

Comment: Why are you using UrlFetchApp instead of the FormaApp?

Comment: If you control the form, you can create a response programmatically and [submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response?hl=en#submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Thanks to @TheMaster's comments we found another roadblock. It seems that you won't be able to easily automate posting to this form unless you have some say on what settings it should have.

The sample form that you shared has enabled the option to "Send responders a copy of their response". This triggers a [CAPTCHA](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1217728) to prevent abuse and the form requires a `g-recaptcha-response` in the POST parameters. I wouldn't go as far as to say that reCAPTCHA is unbeatable but it's not feasible for us to even consider bypassing it. As long as the captcha is in place you won't be able to post to the form with a script.

I made a copy of your form without the setting to send a copy of the responses and this did not ask for a captcha. In that case your script did work, but keep in mind that there are field validations. Your original script was including the header row from the spreadsheet, which did not pass the email validation and can also return a 400 error. You can correct by modifying your range like this:

```js
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Alternatively, you can just keep the range as it is and use [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first element in the array.

```js
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.shift()
```

Still, keep in mind that this will only work for captcha-less Forms. There may be other triggers that enforce captcha so you will probably only be able to automate posting to specific Forms or ones that you have some control over.

Comment: Did you have success with the script?

Comment: Yes, though I didn't test it against OP's form. I built my own that looked the same to review the results. I just modified the datamap so the `entry.xxxxxx` items would match my form and added the `vs.shift()` and the script successfully submitted new answers. Did you get a different result?

Comment: Yes. Even with a valid email and all values as plain strings(removing the sheets dependency completely), I still got 400. I believe it's due to captcha. Google sends a catcha value along with the post. But I'm not sure.

Comment: You're right. My test form didn't ask for a captcha so it worked for me, but OP's sample form does require a captcha. I tried to figure out the reason and it turns out that his form has the "Send responders a copy of their response" option. This forces the captcha, probably to prevent the form from being used as a spam source. I will update my answer with this info.

Comment: Sir sending a mail to user is necessary for my project, how can I achieve it? Btw thanks your answer was very useful.